# How to create multiple module instances in joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I have installed joomla module. It seems that I can only display the same module with the same configuration on any page. 
How do you have this same module, with a different configuration on different page ? (I do not want to display the same rss feed under each joomla article)...

Is it possible to have multiple "instances" of a module ?

I have taken an rss feed module for example, but I could have taken any joomla module.

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frd...its easy..

Pls follow my link:

Administrator--> Extensions--> module manager-->Select ur module(Which module u need)-->click new Button (in top right menu)-->here u got all module (select ur required module)--> now u can get it...!!! pls check it..!!

Answer (score 0):

Modules can be assigned to specific menu items. In 1.5 you have the option to assign a module to All, Selected, or None menu items. Simple make multiple copies of the module you want to use then assign each version to the menu items you wish with the associated variations in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple instances of a module through module manager in Admin side of your site. And different instances can have different configurations.